# How can I dynamically change the keys that Crypt uses in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, encryption

I have been researching how to use [Laravel Encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/encryption) as building a homestead encryption platform is frowned upon and rightfully so.

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::encryptString('This is a secret message from user 1 to user 2');
```

Take the above example, this is using my `APP_KEY` which derives from my `.env` file, generation previously by `php artisan key:generate`. The issue is that user 1 is never issued two sets of keys to communicate **only** to user 2. User 3, 4 and so on could still read this message using the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::decryptString` method.

Currently, my database is set up to have a chat header. This contains information about **what** is communicating. All participants will use these keys for encryption and decryption - thus any outside users not being able to decrypt the messages.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('chat_headers', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->string('private_key')->unique();
        $table->string('public_key')->unique();
    });
}
```

I also have a chat participants, this contains information about **who** is communicating:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('chat_participants', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        # TODO: Build RBAC

        $table->index(['user_id']);
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Finally, I have a table for message logs. This contains the encrypted message followed by what chat room they're associating with.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('chat_messages', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->timestamp('created_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));

        $table->integer('chat_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('message');

        $table->index(['chat_id']);
        $table->foreign('chat_id')->references('id')->on('chat_headers')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

How can I dynamically assign new keys to the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt` to use in order to encrypt messages between a chat party?

If this is not possible, how can I secure the messages between the participants within a chat using these two keys? I feel like using `Crypt` for this is 'encrypting for the sake of it' and not actually hiding the content of anything between users.

Comment: Interesting question! Might be a little broad though; changing the underlying logic of a build-in component of Laravel is not a trivial task. You can update config values on the fly, via `Config::set("APP_KEY", "private_key");`, which *should* update the key used in `Crypt::encrypt()` and `Crypt::decrypt()` function, but you'd have to do that prior to every call, which could get tedious.

Comment: I thought that would be an option but the performance would be revolting. I have tried to research if Laravel has such a tool to deal with encryption and decryption but I only found the `Crypt` facade. Is there a way I can achieve the same without using `Crypt` in the case it being broad. I just need to secure the communication to the participants, rather than just encrypting for the sake of it. Thanks! @TimLewis

Comment: Yeah, performance and if you needed to make a change, you'd have to do it in a lot of places. As far as not using Laravel's `Crypt` function, there likely is, but I'm not positive what that would be. This does however sound like how `GPG` works for encrypting messages, so maybe taking a look at/getting familiar with that could help? https://gpgtools.org/ for reference.

Comment: I looked at similar tools but I think its more than what I need. I did look at using PHP functions like `openssl_pkey_new()` and vise versa to assign the keys then manually encrypt and decrypt the messages but I'm not sure how to do this since I assume `openssl_*` will only generate one key where as I need multiple, then saying that, after creating a key - I have no clue how to encrypt and decrypt with the key. @TimLewis

Comment: Yeah, I would agree that's a safe assumption. Unfortunately, this is beyond my personal scope of knowledge, but hopefully someone else can give you a hand. If you haven't heard much in a couple days, you can offer a bounty on this question; give someone a bit more incentive to help. Best of luck!

Comment: All I know about encryption is the concept of PKI. A user is issued two sets of keys, in my case - the chat holds the keys. The participants then receive the public key when they join the chat room to encrypt the messages. The participants then use the chat private key to read messages. Doing this is a whole-nother level for my personal knowledge also haha! Thanks for the help though! @TimLewis

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would recommend against using the Crypt facade directly and would instead recommend using the Laravel Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter which is the class that is used for the Crypt facade (I'm on Laravel 5.6).

Here is a little code snippet that I hope will help:

```
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;

//Keys and cipher used by encrypter(s)
$fromKey = base64_decode("from_key_as_a_base_64_encoded_string");
$toKey = base64_decode("to_key_as_a_base_64_encoded_string");
$cipher = "AES-256-CBC"; //or AES-128-CBC if you prefer

//Create two encrypters using different keys for each
$encrypterFrom = new Encrypter($fromKey, $cipher);
$encrypterTo = new Encrypter($toKey, $cipher);

//Decrypt a string that was encrypted using the "from" key
$decryptedFromString = $encrypterFrom->decryptString("gobbledygook=that=is=a=from=key=encrypted=string==");

//Now encrypt the decrypted string using the "to" key
$encryptedToString = $encrypterTo->encryptString($decryptedFromString);
```

If you would like to see the facade loading code it is in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.